# Unity3D - How to make effect between scenes with UI Mask or Shader

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, scale, mask, masking

How can we make an effect of "end scene" using UI Masks scaling or an Shader in Unity?

Thus:

[image]

Also as at the end of cartoon where the center circle decreases until the screen goes completely dark. (Scale)

Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this with UI mask. UI mask only masks UI elements.

You can do a couple of tutorials on shaders to learn how to write this shader. But easier would be to have a second camera rendering on top of the first doing this blackout. The blackout can be a spritesheet animation.

Comment: Hi @Nika Kasradze Thanks for attention, but I would have an explanatory example of how this can be done using two cameras? How "camera rendering on top of the first doing this blackout" ?

Comment: Please watch [this tutorial for 2 cameras](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YV64Xx8wjWk) and [any of these for sprite sheet animation tutorials](https://www.google.ge/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=NRtfV4uyCoqnsAHu3KH4CQ#q=unity+sprite+sheet+animation&tbm=vid). Finally, you'd play the sprite sheet animation in the camera overlaying your main camera.